# Cannot return user data in UserAccountsDrawerHeader with FirebaseStore/Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having an issue with returning user's email in UserAccountsDrawerHeader. In the **future: FirebaseStore** i do get an error: Undefined name 'FirebaseDatabase'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. Maybe someone has any clue why FirebaseDatabase it comes out as a fault.

Thank you in advance!

**My code snippet**

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountEmail: FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseStore.instance
                .collection("Users")
                .doc(widget.uid)
                .once(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.value['email']);
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }),
```

Comment: are you using firestore or firebase realtime database?

Comment: Hey @peter is was following your tutorials, but i decided to edit old code due to some changes in app and stay with FirebaseFirestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase offers two kind of database services: Realtime database and Firestore, so if you are using Firestore then you have to do the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("Users")
                .doc(widget.uid)
                .get(),
```

And if you are using realtime database then do:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
                .reference()
                .child(widget.uid),
                .once()
```

Comment: I have done before, but i have decided to switch from Realtime database to Firestore @peter

Comment: Sorry, for waiting, but the use with FirebaseStore - Undefined name 'FirebaseDatabase' still exists

Comment: there is no class called `FirebaseStore` please check the answer, its `FirebaseFirestore`

Comment: My bad i haven't noticed it, thank you once more @peter . Also there was another issue, I needed to change **AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot**  to **AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot**, as well as **snapshot.data.value** to **snapshot.data**